# IIS requirements for ASMX webservice

Tags: asp.net, web-services, iis

I'm a windows-forms developer who was asked to make a webservice. I've took the visual studio and made one. It works on several servers, but in one in particular (new server and fresh installation), it doesn't. The client ask me to exactly define which modules of IIS do I need to be installed, and I don't know (I'm not a server administrator; I don't even know which modules there are).

So, which IIS 7.5 modules should I ask to be installed in order to run an asmx webservice based on the 3.5 framework?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Is .Net 3.5 installed on that server ?

Comment: yes, it is. it's a windows 2012 server. thank you for your answer!